# Update a managed metadata column with multiple values using CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, office365-apps

I have the following code inside my remote event reciever, to create a new folder, and then populate the folder managed metadata fields with the current item (item that was added) values:-

```
ListItem listItem = context.Web.GetList(webrelativeurl +  "/"+i2["TemplateListUrl"]).AddItem(listItemCreationInformation);

listItem["FolderType"] = currentitem["FolderType"];
listItem["CorpType"] = currentitem["CorpType"];
```

now the `FodlerType` on both the current item and the listitem is a managed metadata column which allow single value only, while the `CorpType` allow multiple values. my above code will assign a value for the `FolderType` correctly, but will raise this error when updating the `CorpType`:-

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestException
>   HResult=0x80131500   Message=The object is not associated with an
>   object identity or the object identity is invalid.   Source=   StackTrace:

any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a [`TaxonomyFieldValueCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj166171%28v%3Doffice.15%29) use the [`SetFieldValueByValueCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj165507(v=office.15)) of the [`TaxonomyField`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj165648(v=office.15)) object.

```cs
var field = item.ParentList.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("CorpType");
var corpTypeTaxField = context.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field);
context.Load(item,i=>i[TaxKeywordFieldName]);
var valuesToCopy = corpTypeTaxField.GetFieldValueByValueCollection(currentitem["CorpType"].ToString());
corpTypeTaxField.SetFieldValueByValueCollection(listItem, valuesToCopy);
```

Note, this gets a lot messier if you have terms that you need to look up to construct a `TaxonomyFieldValueCollection` from scratch -- copying it from another item is definitely easier.